# Problem in displaying selected value in dropdown in Mozilla iPhone client

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to change value of a dropdown dynamically using JQuery.I changed the client in Mozilla to Iphone.Whatever value i am setting does not display in dropdown it stays same.

Anyone got any clue? This is the code to change the value of dropdown.

```
    jQuery("#billingAddressState").val('CA')
```

Comment: What is the question? What doesn't work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there's always the other way round, try:

```
jQuery('#billingAddressState option').removeAttr('selected').filter('[value="CA"]').attr('selected', 'selected');
```

Comment: This should work nicely - you'll technically only need the .removeAttr('selected') if it's a multiple select box.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's a bit late but I got the same issue while working with firefox 3.6 select tags and this is what I did to solve it

```
 jQuery('#billingAddressState option[value="CA"]').prop('selected', 'selected');
```

according to the jquery site we are supposed [To retrieve and change DOM properties such as the checked, selected, or disabled state of form elements, use the .prop() method](http://api.jquery.com/attr/).